# How to get the return value of the callback function from a request which is exported as a module

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, callback, node-modules

I'm trying to parse the names and birthdays of all the presidents of USA. First I get all the urls. I have previously exported a module in which I am trying to return an object containing the name and birthday of the president, by calling a request using the URL. I am unable to retrieve the data in the main js file.

I am trying to do this without using promises.

The module I am exporting :

```
const request = require('request'); //to make HTML requests
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const POTUSParse = function(url){
   return request(url,(error,response,HTML) => {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        const $ = cheerio.load(HTML);
        const presidentName = $("#firstHeading").text();
        const bdayString = $(".bday").text();

        return {
            "name" : presidentName,
            "bday" : bdayString
        };
    }
   });

}


module.exports = POTUSParse;
```

The main JS file :

```
const POTUSParse = require('./getName&BDAYModule');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');


request("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States",(error,response,html) => {
    if(error || response.statusCode != 200){
        return;
    }

    const wikiURLs = [];
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $("big a").each((index,rawDOMElement) => {
        wikiURLs.push($(rawDOMElement).attr("href"));
    });

    for(var i=0;i<wikiURLs.length;i++){
        console.log(POTUSParse("https://en.wikipedia.org" + wikiURLs[i]));
    }
});
```

I am getting an object which the request module returns. How can I get the return value of the callback function ?

Comment: How do you plan on knowing when the POTUSParse request has a response if you do not use a promise or async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simpler ways to achieve your asynchronous behaviour by using an awaitable request library and then using async/await instead of callbacks.

The best way to get your current code working is to return a promise in your exported function which is resolved by the callback:

```
const request = require('request'); //to make HTML requests
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const POTUSParse = function(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, (error, response, HTML) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(HTML);
        const presidentName = $("#firstHeading").text();
        const bdayString = $(".bday").text();

        resolve({
          "name": presidentName,
          "bday": bdayString
        });
      }
    })
  })

}    

module.exports = POTUSParse;
```

You can then watch for the promise to be resolved:

```
const POTUSParse = require('./getName&BDAYModule');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');


request("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States",(error,response,html) => {
    if(error || response.statusCode != 200){
        return;
    }

    const wikiURLs = [];
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $("big a").each((index,rawDOMElement) => {
        wikiURLs.push($(rawDOMElement).attr("href"));
    });

    for(var i=0;i<wikiURLs.length;i++){
        POTUSParse("https://en.wikipedia.org" + wikiURLs[i]).then(potus => console.log(potus));
    }
});
```